# maven .zip publish or upload error 302 to jfrog artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins

Jenkins fails to upload .zip file to jfrog using generic artifactory. Not sure what i am missing.

1 artifacts were found

Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 302. HTTP response message: Found
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:80)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:340)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:173)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 302. HTTP response message: Found
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.throwHttpIOException(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:743)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:623)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:329)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:181)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:153)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:121)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to mesos-jenkins-fa74d0edd0b147ac9fe44a9d7655e401-alm_mesos_cloud(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:979)
    ... 9 more

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is resolved seems i was using wrong URL of artifactory, but still the error message was not pointing exact error

But i will consider this Question as close for now